# HOW TO VIEW THE V8.LOG CREATED AFTER RUNNING NODE-PROFILER

Tags: node.js, profiling, v8

profiler to check on cpu profiling of my node.js server.It created a log called as v8.log.I also downloaded the node-tick-processor it created data as below

```
Statistical profiling result from v8.log, (298287 ticks, 2 unaccounted, 0 excluded).

 [Unknown]:
  ticks  total  nonlib   name
  2    0.0%

[Shared libraries]:
ticks  total  nonlib   name
295618   99.1%    0.0%  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
1999    0.7%    0.0%  /usr/local/bin/node
119    0.0%    0.0%  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
 59    0.0%    0.0%  7fff509b3000-7fff509b5000
  5    0.0%    0.0%  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
```

I've no idea on the above log.Any help regarding this is much useful.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem. Try installing the "tick" processor instead. I think it is more compatible with many versions of node: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tick. Also if you are on a mac, make sure you pass in "--mac" when running it.